# Cannot delete old MariaDB 5.5.4 End-of Life on 31.01

Tags: swisscomdev

Migrated successfully to new **MariaDB** Service. Kept the old just in case.

Now I am not able to delete the old service via **Web Console**. 
Message: **Delete App** bindings and **Service** keys first.

But: There are no app bindings and service keys cannot be deleted due to '**internal server erro**r'.

So what's to do?

Answer (score 0):

I am confident you already solved this, but just in case. You will have to reach out to the Swisscom Support System and send them a message at the bottom of this page: https://developer.swisscom.com/support

They will be able to delete the service instance for you.

PS: don't forget to include your Organization / Space / Service Name in that correspondence (not here)